# Using Jquery Ajax POST on Node.js Express site

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

Everything is working fine with the forms post requests I've done so far, but when I try to make an Ajax call I'm not able to deal with it on the server. Although it returns the 'succeed' param, I'm not able to save the information on the database nor make any acions with it on the server.

page.jade:

```
script
        (function () {

            $('ul').find('a').on("click", function () {
                var option = $(this).data('res');
                $('article').animate({ 'margin-left': -600 });
                console.log(option + ' ' + #{idn});

                var envio = {resultado: option, idupdate: #{idn}};

                $.ajax({
                        url: '/',
                        type: "post",
                        data: JSON.stringify(envio),
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log('success');
                        }
                    });
            });
        })();
```

server.js

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {

    var Resultado = req.body.resultado;
    var idUpdate = req.body.idupdate;

    if (Resultado == "yes") {
        connection.query('UPDATE questions SET yes=yes+1 WHERE id=' + idUpdate + ');');
    } else {
        connection.query('UPDATE questions SET no=no+1 WHERE id=' + idUpdate + ');');
    }
});
```

I tried to find any similar situation around, but the information on this particular case is scarce. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like both querys are malformed,

```
connection.query('UPDATE questions SET yes=yes+1 WHERE id=' + idUpdate + ');');
                                                           (here)   ----^   
connection.query('UPDATE questions SET no=no+1 WHERE id=' + idUpdate + ');');
                                                     (and here)   ----^
```

Then, remove  `+ ');'`  part and it should work.

Like:

```
connection.query('UPDATE questions SET yes=yes+1 WHERE id=' + idUpdate);
```

Aditionaly you need to end the request, calling `res.end()`

final code:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {

    var Resultado = req.body.resultado;
    var idUpdate = req.body.idupdate;

    if (Resultado == "yes") {
        connection.query('UPDATE questions SET yes=yes+1 WHERE id=' + idUpdate);
    } else {
        connection.query('UPDATE questions SET no=no+1 WHERE id=' + idUpdate);
    }
    res.end(); // must be called.
});
```

Comment: yep! That was it! Thanks @3boll ! Now the query is writing to the database, but I's not returning the success param back to the console. Any idea?

Comment: Note, this query is wide-open to SQL injection. You should be using prepared statements or escaping the ID with `connection.escape(idUpdate)`. Example: Submit an ID of `1 OR 1=1` would update the yes count on *every* question.

Comment: @loganfsmyth , could you tell me a good article I can study about it? Thanks a lot